# WCF Service with version

Tags: asp.net, wcf, webforms, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am new on working with WCF service, I am using ADO.Net Entity Data Model, Name it -> DogModel.edmx.
where the Dogs table has ID,Name and Age. It's working fine. but, i wanted to understand the concept behind the version.

Here is code for IDog.cs,

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IDog
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Author GetAuthorById(string authorId);


    }


[DataContract]
    public class DogType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        int id = 0;
        string name = string.Empty;
        int age = 0;

        [DataMember]
        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string NAME
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int AGE
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code i have placed on Dog.cs,

```
public class Dog : IDog
    {
        public Author GetAuthorById(string dogId)
        {
            using (DogEntities pubs = new DogEntities())
            {
                DogType d = new DogType();
                var dog = (from p in pubs.Dogs
                              where p.Id == dogId
                              select p).First();

                d.ID = author.ID;
                d.NAME = author.Name;
                d.AGE = author.Age;

                return d;
            }
        }
}
```

"If i make a new version of the service then i need to just expose a new end". what does that mean, pls explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF Versioning is not easy to explain in a couple of lines.

There are a couple of different routes you can take, depending on the changes you make to your service, namely:

- Non-strict versioning
- Semi-strict versioning
- Strict versioning

Michele Leroux Bustamante wrote a great two part series on this issue, check it out here:

- [Versioning WCF Services, Part 1](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/versioning-wcf-services-part-i)
- [Versioning WCF Services, Part 2](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/versioning-wcf-services-part-ii)

Another great resource to read up on WCF versioning strategies is MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx

Comment: Links are dead.  Here's the same part 1 article: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/windows-communication-foundation-wcf2/versioning-wcf-services-part-i-122538   And part 2: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/windows-communication-foundation-wcf2/versioning-wcf-services-part-ii-122514